# XCode, Git and MediaTemple (gs)

Tags: xcode, git, mediatemple

I'm wondering if anyone's managed to connect to a self-hosted Git repository on a Mediatemple GridServer (gs) via XCode? I tried setting this up last night, and this is as far as I've got:

1. Installed Git on my Mac(s)
2. Created subdomain for git (git.blahblah.com) on my gs service via Terminal SSH
3. Created empty repository within subdomain (git.blahblah.com/repo/repo.git) via Terminal SSH
4. Clicked on 'Connect to repo' from XCode's launch menu
5. Entered repo address (ssh://git.blahblah.com:22/repo/repo.git) in XCode's address bar
6. Clicked 'clone' once XCode has found the repo and is telling me that "Authentication [is] required"
7. Chosen the appropriate local folder on my machine to clone the repo to
8. Tried to enter username and password specified in MT admin panel - the same ones that I used via Terminal SSH to set up the repo in the first place
9. Get booted with an error message: either 'incorrect username and password' (they're not) or 'specified address does not appear to be a repository, connection unexpectedly terminated by host' (or similar)
10. Cry. Repeatedly.

Getting to step 6 causes my IP to be blocked by MT, even if I'm logged into the web control panel from the same IP at the same time. Unblocking the IP via the MT control panel has no effect; the IP is blocked as soon as I try and connect via XCode again.

I suspect it's actually step 4 that's causing problems as XCode is trying to 'ping' the repo without credentials as you type in the address (to resolve connectivity).

Has anyone got this working, or do I need to look at hosting my Git repos elsewhere? I'd rather not spend more money on hosting when I have a service that should suit this purpose sitting unused.

Comment: Did you try to enter username into git repo address? Eg. ssh://serveradmin%blahblah.com@git.blahblah.com:22/repo/repo.git Also, you don't need to install git on your Mac(s) in order to use git with Xcode (not that it has any effect, it's just not required).

Comment: I did try that last night while on webchat with MT support, and it didn't work - but that could be because the IP was already blocked at that point. I'll try again later, when I get back to my machines.

Comment: How about trying `ssh://git.blahblah.com/repo/repo.git` (without the `:22`)?

Comment: I've tried both; the reason I'm using the port number is because it's supposed to force the server into ssh. I'll try it without later but I don't think that's the cause...

Comment: Nope, no luck with any of those. Getting rather frustrated :(

Comment: I'd use a dedicated Git client like [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) (free) or [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com) ($59, 30 days trial). Xcode's Git support is quite poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update: the solution I've managed to get working is to set up an account on BitBucket, create a project and add it to local Git, commit that to BitBucket and then connect to BitBucket using XCode. I downloaded SourceTree for extra Git activity as per Stefan's suggestion, as I'm still not 100% comfortable using Terminal (I just like GUIs, is that wrong?).

Everything seems to be running smoothly so far; it's just a little annoying that I had to use a third party for Git when I thought my server (which I'm already paying for) could do the job.

Answer (score 1):

After several online sessions with MediaTemple support I've come to the conclusion that it's not going to work.

While I can host a repository on my own gs service just fine, the way that XCode tries to connect to it causes my IP to be blocked every single time. As the blocking is automatic (and can't be turned off) then it seems XCode and MediaTemple have reached an impasse.

It's not a huge issue as I'm the only developer on this project, and I can always use DropBox instead (I was just trying to find a better way of keeping versioned backups across my laptop and desktop). If I really need Git I can use another tool or Terminal.

If I had to point fingers, I'd blame XCode: it seems its support for Git is rather sketchy beyond connecting to an open, gitHub-hosted repository.